# How to prove $\cos 4x-\cos 4y=8(\cos x-\cos y)(\cos x+\cos y)(\cos x-\sin y)(\cos x+\sin y)$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that 
$$\cos 4x-\cos 4y=8(\cos x-\cos y)(\cos x+\cos y)(\cos x-\sin y)(\cos x+\sin y)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be viewed as a consequence of relationship

$$\cos(4x)=8 \cos(x)^4 - 8\cos(x)^2 + 1$$

Remark: Any $\cos(nx)$ can be expressed as a polynomial in $\cos(x)$ ; these polynomials are known as [Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) $T_n(\cos(\theta))$.

Setting $X:=cos(x)$ and $Y:=\cos(y)$, it amounts to prove the now non-trigonometric identity:

$$8(X^4-Y^4)-8(X^2-Y^2)=8(X-Y)(X+Y)(X-s\sqrt{1-Y^2})(X+s\sqrt{1-Y^2})$$

(where $s=1$ if $y$ is in the first 2 quadrants: $0 \leq (y \ mod \ 2 \pi) \leq \pi) $, $-1$ otherwise ; this is necessary to take into account the sign of $\sin(y)$).

or

$$8(X^2-Y^2)(X^2+Y^2)-8(X^2-Y^2)=8(X^2-Y^2)(X^2-(1-Y^2))$$

which is immediately proven.

Comment: i did not  understand...what u are trying to say.............

Comment: Please, say me where you don't understand.

Comment: the second part...

Comment: I have modified a little my answer (I had forgotten the "8" for example). Relationship $\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y=1\  \Longrightarrow \ (\sin y)^2=1-(\cos y)^2 \  \Longrightarrow \ \sin y = \sqrt{1-(\cos y)^2} = \sqrt{1-Y^2}$. This is valid when $\sin y \geq 0$ ; when $\sin y \leq 0$, we have to take the sign$-1$ into account by using $s=-1$... I agree that it is the slightly difficult part....

Comment: ok now i get it thnx

Comment: For the colleagues who have voted for closing this question: I think that all "trigonometric identities" are not equal. The interest of this one is real in the needed methodology: comparing both sides etc...

Answer (score 0):

For the Right hand side, use

$$2(\cos x+\cos y)(\cos x-\cos y)=2\cos^2x-2\cos^2y=1+\cos2x-(1+\cos2y)$$

$$2(\cos x+\sin y)(\cos x-\sin y)=2\cos^2x-2\sin^2y=1+\cos2x-(1-\cos2y)=\cos2x-\cos2y$$

$$2(\cos x+\cos y)(\cos x-\cos y)\cdot2(\cos x+\sin y)(\cos x-\sin y)=(\cos2x+\cos2y)(\cos2x-\cos2y)$$

Now, $$2(\cos2x+\cos2y)(\cos2x-\cos2y)=2\cos^22x-2\cos^22y=1+\cos4x-(1+\cos4y)=?$$

Comment: @JeanMarie,  Please pinpoint your confusion in understanding my method?

Comment: I am very sorry; This answer wasn't intended at all at you, but at the people who wanted this question to be closed. I displace the answer...